# Bug in the MQTT Tcl API?

Tags: tcl, mqtt

I am using the [Tcl MQTT API](https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/mqtt/index) to run a simple subscriber client with code

```
source mqtt.tcl

proc message_callback { topic message } {
    puts stderr "message on topic $topic: $message"
}

set client [mqtt new]
$client connect my-client $::addr
$client subscribe {BCDS/#} message_callback

vwait _done
```

and it works fine with a local broker, eg. mosquitto running on the same LAN (at least found no problems while I ran it).

But with a broker over the internet, eg. iot.eclipse.org, after printing a couple of messages

```
message on topic BCDS/XDK/single/20:19:AB:F4:04:56/out/stream:  
{"sn":"20:19:AB:F4:04:56","data":{"acc":
{"x":26,"y":32,"z":1012,"unit":"mG"},"gyro":{"x":1220,"y":-6835,"z":-
2319,"unit":"mdeg/s"},"mag":{"x":40,"y":1,"z":-4,"unit":"uT"},"light":
{"value":7466,"unit":"mLux"},"temp":
{"value":50000,"unit":"mCelsius"},"pressure":
{"value":98897,"unit":"Pascal"},"humidity":{"value":39,"unit":"%rh"}}}
message on topic BCDS/XDK/single/20:19:AB:F4:04:53/out/stream: 
{"sn":"20:19:AB:F4:04:53","data":{"acc":
{"x":26,"y":32,"z":1012,"unit":"mG"},"gyro":{"x":1220,"y":-6835,"z":-
2319,"unit":"mdeg/s"},"mag":{"x":40,"y":1,"z":-4,"unit":"uT"},"light":
{"value":13617,"unit":"mLux"},"temp":
{"value":50000,"unit":"mCelsius"},"pressure":
{"value":98897,"unit":"Pascal"},"humidity":{"value":39,"unit":"%rh"}}}2ú
,BCDS/XDK/single/20:19:AB:F4:04:52
/out/strea{"sn":"20:19:AB:F4:04:52","data":{"acc":
{"x":26,"y":32,"z":1012,"unit":"mG"},"gyro":{"x":1220,"y":-6835,"z":-
2319,"unit":"mdeg/s"},"mag":{"x":40,"y":1,"z":-4,"unit":"uT"},"light":
{"value":7789,"unit":"mLux"},"temp":{"value":50000,"unit":"mCelsius"},
```

it fails within 10 seconds with a stack trace

```
1507901608909 (::oo::Obj22_coro): can't read "msgid": no such variable
while executing
"dict set rc msgid $msgid"
    (class "::mqtt" method "receive" line 35)
    invoked from within
"my receive"
    (class "::mqtt" method "listen" line 27)
    invoked from within
"my listen"
```

My debugging indicates that this API does not handle concatenated messages over a connection? Am I correct? Has anyone used this API to do anything substantial?

Comment: try changing the client-id `my-client` to something random to ensure it's not clashing with an existing client.

Comment: There is only one connection, and it prints some messages, but fails within 10 seconds. Modified my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has since been fixed

https://chiselapp.com/user/schelte/repository/mqtt/tktview?name=4d83cc2c30

and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bug. This is not a good channel for reporting bugs; Stack Overflow is for more general support questions.

However, you conveniently link to the Fossil repository for the package, so that's where you'd report the bug (Fossil is nice like that). It's a <kbd>Ticket</kbd> → `New ticket`, and you can log in anonymously and report a ticket at that point (please leave your contact details if you're in as anon; it lets the author get back in contact with you if necessary).

Comment: If you had checked the link you recommend you would have seen my ticket.